# Passing Variable to jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to change the class of the elements prior to a button only for when that button is clicked.  Want to change class of item 1 when button that corresponds to item 1 is clicked.  How do I pass the var index as the selector in .toggleClass?

Thx.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var index = $(this).index()-1;
        $(?).toggleClass(function(n) {
            return 'color';
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add your HTML also

Comment: where is the html part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).prev().toggleClass('color');
    });
});
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the previous sibling element of the button clicked. `$(this)` of course is the button, and [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) will return the previous sibling. There is no need to pass a function to toggleClass, since the function is only returning a string with no logic. You can just use a string.

Comment: That works, thank you.  I'm extremely new to this and overcomplicated it with a Variable.  Again, thank you.